# Best practice for sharing an Observable-collection with nested properties

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, viewmodel

1. I have an observable collection that is shared between different viewmodels.

```
public class UserInput1ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public ObservableCollection<ParamClass> ParamColl { get; set; }

        public UserInput1ViewModel(<ParamClass> paramColl)
        {
            this.ParamColl = paramColl;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }       

        private void UpdateCollection()
        {            
            this.ParamList = PerformCalculations();

        }

}

public class ParamClass
{
        public double Property1 { get; set; }
        public double Property2 { get; set; }
        public double Property3 { get; set; }
        ...                   ...
        ...                   ...
        public double Property19 { get; set; }

}
```

2. The function `PerformCalculations()` will execute, but it will not update the all the properties inside the observable collection. I have learned that you cannot do that with observable collection https://stackoverflow.com/a/9984424/4387406.
3. So, this is what I am currently doing.

```
        private void UpdateCollection()
        {            
            var output = PerformCalculations();
            for(int i = 0; i < output.Count(); i++)
            {
                this.ParamColl[i].Property1 = output[i].Property1;
                this.ParamColl[i].Property2 = output[i].Property2;
                       ...                   ...
                       ...                   ...
                this.ParamColl[i].Property19 = output[i].Property19;
            }
        }
```

4. My question is: is there a better way of sharing observable collection?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to make `ParamColl[i].Property1 = output[i].Property1;` update the UI, ParamClass would have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If PerformCalculations returns a collection of ParamClass, you could certainly write `ParamColl[i] = output[i];`

Comment: Thank you Clemens, I thought the INotifyPropertyChanged interface was only for viewmodels. This is great learning for me !Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the GUI to update whenever a property of an instance in a list changes, you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the instance class, just as you have done in your `ViewModel`.

You haven't shown what your `ParamClass` looks like so I'm using a `Person` class in place. You could do the same thing as you've done in your `ViewModel`.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    private int age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Now, if even a single property in any of the instances is changed it will be reflected on your GUI.

Since you're using WPF, there's quite a few good `MVVM` tool-kits out there that will do a lot of this for you. For instance, [`MVVM Light Toolkit`](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) is one such examples. There's many others out there.

Comment: Hi Sach, Thank you very much for your answer. I did not know that you could apply INotifyPropertyChanged interface to instance class as well. I thought it was only for the viewModel classes. Cool! This is awesome. I am just learning the workings of MVVM (and I know my program is implementing a bad one). Thank you for the link to the toolkit. I will definitely learn to use the MVVM Light Toolkit. Thanks !!1